# How to add several images in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to add images in an Excel Sheet using ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert
I want to obtain the name of the pictures from activeCell and using it to add the images that have the same name in a specific folder, the code is like this:

```
Dim name As String, name1 As String

name = ActiveCell.Value
name1 = "Folder location" + name + "_1.jpg"

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert( _
        name1).Select
```

the code works only for one cell, but them when I use another cell, with a different name of a picture that is also in the same folder, it only adds a square saying “The Picture can't be displayed”

I am using Mac Os and Microsoft Excel 16.56

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you keep producing correct file paths? Check if they actually exist: `If Len(Dir(name1)) = 0 Then: Debug.Print (name1 & " does not exist!")`. Maybe your `ActiveCell` is not where you expect it to be. E.g. if you keep using `.Select`; the instance used above is already unnecessary for this particular procedure.

Comment: Thanks, I used `If Len(Dir(name1)) = 0 Then: Debug.Print (name1 & " does not exist!").` and I found that I needed to authorize the access to the files, So I used `filePermissionCandidates = Array(name1, name2)
  fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)`. Now the code Works